# vb.net - Comparing two text files and retrieving a specific value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagrid

**this question is related to my previous questions**

I'm currently working on a Registration form where all the details of a student are save in a text file.

I populated the combobox using a textfile.

The format of these values are for example: (code~school name) SCH001~Saint 
Thomas College

this is how I saved the details in a text file:

```
Dim firstname, lastname, email, mobile, level, currentschool, currenttrack, institution1, institution2, institution3, institution4, institution5, institution6, courses1, courses2, courses3, macaddress, eventcode, idseq, filename, logfiledirectory, targetdirectory, log, configdir, printschool As String
    firstname = txtFName.Text
    lastname = txtLName.Text
    email = txtEmail.Text
    mobile = txtMobile.Text
    level = cmbLevel.Text
    currenttrack = cmbCurrentTrack.Text
    printschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text
    currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.SelectedValue
    institution1 = cmbInstitution1.SelectedValue
    institution2 = cmbInstitution2.SelectedValue
    institution3 = cmbInstitution3.SelectedValue
    institution4 = cmbInstitution4.SelectedValue
    institution5 = cmbInstitution5.SelectedValue
    institution6 = cmbInstitution6.SelectedValue
    courses1 = cmbCourse1.SelectedValue
    courses2 = cmbCourse2.SelectedValue
    courses3 = cmbCourse3.SelectedValue

    If mobile = "" Then
        mobile = "09000000000"
    End If

    If firstname = "" Or lastname = "" Or email = "" Or level = "" Or currentschool = "" Or currenttrack = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the required fields!", "Registration", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
```

I have a datagridview where all the saved details in a text file are shown.
here's a screenshot of my datagridview:
[image]

**WHAT I WANT TO DO: I want to retrieve the School name using the current school code (refer to the image) from the source text file(the one I used to populated my comboboxes). Instead of the school code, I want the School name to be shown in the datagridview.**
**Is there a possible way to do it?**

I hope you guys understand what im trying to say.
Im new here.

Comment: Its so easy. search for the _school code_ in the textfile contents. After getting the line, split the line on '~'. Now I really wanna know, how much do you actually tried by yourself. As I provided answers for both the previous questions. You could have learned it all by now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again just like I answered last time, use this function:

```
Function FetchSchoolName(schoolcode As String, filepath As String) As String
    Dim filecontents = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
    For Each line As String In filecontents
        If (line.Contains(schoolcode.Trim())) Then
            Return line.Split("~"c)(1)
        End If
    Next
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

Example text entry:

```
sch001~abcinstitute
sch002~myacademy
sch003~someschoolname
```

Then pass the schoolcode(which you get from the datagridview) and filepath in the top-most function

```
MessageBox.Show(FetchSchoolName("sch002", "C:\Users\nobody\Desktop\somefile.txt"))
```

Output:

> myacademy

Now in respect to your `DataGridView`, wherever you are filling(source binding) it use the above method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce the same output as Nobody's answer but without looping, you can use LINQ, this also uses less lines of code but achieves the same output

```
Dim query = filecontents.Where(Function(x) x.Contains(schoolcode)).Select(Function(x) x.Split("~")(1)).FirstOrDefault
Return query.ToString()
```

Comment: Upvoting your answer because I liked it better than mine :)

Comment: @Nobody Thanks, you did most of the work tho, I just provided an alternative to looping :)

Comment: My Linq knowledge is a bit hit-or-miss. So went with the foreach version :] Nonetheless I learned something. Thanks a ton ;]